# moving TTLauncherView from sdk3.x to sdk4.0 adds an ugly shadow to TTLauncherItem's badge

Tags: iphone, ios4, three20, ttlauncherview, ttlauncheritem

We are moving an app from iOS3.x to iOS4. 
Now a shadow shows up for the TTLauncherItem's badge, as show in the image.

**How to get rid of that shadow?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the same issue, upgrading to the latest three20 fixed it up